# Difference between zero-padding and character-padding in Recurrent Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, nlp, rnn, sequence-to-sequence

For RNN's to work efficiently we vectorize the problem which results in an input matrix of shape

```
    (m, max_seq_len)
```

where m is the number of examples, e.g. sentences, and max_seq_len is the maximum length that a sentence can have. Some examples have a smaller lengths than this max_seq_len. A solution is to pad these sentences.

One method to pad the sentences is called "zero-padding". This means that each sequence is padded by zeros. For example, given a vocabulary where each word is related to some index number, we can represent a sentence with length 4,

```
    "I am very confused"
```

by

```
    [23, 455, 234, 90]
```

Padding it to achieve a max_seq_len=7, we obtain a sentence represented by:

```
    [23, 455, 234, 90, 0, 0, 0]
```

The index 0 is not part of the vocabulary.

Another method to pad is to add a padding character, e.g. "<<pad>>", in our sentence:

```
    "I am very confused <<pad>>> <<pad>> <<pad>>"
```

to achieve the max_seq_len=7. We also add "<<pad>>" in our vocabulary. Let's say it's index is 1000. Then the sentence is represented by

```
    [23, 455, 234, 90, 1000, 1000, 1000]
```

I have seen both methods used, but why is one used over the other? Are there any advantages or disadvantages comparing zero-padding with character-padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If implemented properly, there should be no difference. The very first thing that happens with the indices is corresponding embeddings are loaded. From this perspective, there is no difference between having the pad embedding at the 0th or at the 1000th position.

When you use padding, you should always do masking on the output and other places where it is relevant (i.e., when computing the attention distribution in attention), which ensures no gradient gets propagated from the "non-existing" padding positions.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such difference between zero padding & character padding ,as we applying padding to extract the edges & gradients to form the object for better learning with respect to human vision.

Even with images mostly people use zero padding which creates black background but depending on the datasets & problem statement padding has to change but yes mostly zero padding works for more then 80% of the use cases,this is one of the reason as no one want to research they just applying blindly.